# Effect size in an R mixed model with transformed dependent variable

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have a mixed effect model with my dependent variable transformed using a square root and my indepent variables mean centered. I woudl like to know how to obtain the effect size of the variables.

```
lme(sqrt(Frequency.IAN) ~  scale(Mean.centered.variable1) + scale(Mean.centered.variable2) + scale(Mean.centered.variable3), random = ~ 1+ Time.point| Subject, data=df , method='ML' )
```

Thank you!

Comment: write it to an object ; ```mdl <- lme(sqrt(Frequency.IAN) ~ ...) ``` and for fixed effects, do ```fixef(mdl)``` and for random effects ```ranef(mdl)```

Comment: But I dont get the real effect size, because I have the data transformed.

Comment: then u need to multiply the coefficients by the standard deviation of the variable